# Custom Android date formatting respecting current Locale

Tags: android, localization

Is there a way how to specify dateFormat elements and respect current locale rules? I know that I can use `SimpleDateFormat` and specify the format I like - but it may be wrong in different country.

I tried to mask the elements in `DateFormat` but it accepts only SHORT, MEDIUM and LONG:

```
DateFormat dayMonth = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH_FIELD | DateFormat.MONTH_FIELD);

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal date style: 11
at java.text.DateFormat.checkDateStyle(DateFormat.java:843)
at java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.java:378)
```

I want to get "Oct 2016", or "Říj 2016". This can be implemented with:

```
DateFormat dayMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
```

But I do not want to hard code this format in my app. I see one way only: put it into strings.xml and a translator will have to set it up. Or is there better way?

Comment: Have you looked at `LocalDateTime` - perhaps this might be something you are looking for? An example would be:  `LocalDateTime.parse("2016-07-22")`

Comment: Interesting class, but its format method takes DateTimeFormatter as argument - we are back at my question.

Comment: I see, and what about the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`, its `format` method takes a `TemporalAccessor` - which can be `LocalDateTime.parse("2016-07-22")`.

Comment: I want to format, not parse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android has [`DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getBestDateTimePattern(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String)) to achieve this

```
pattern = DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), "MMMyyyy");
dayMonth = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
```

The only downside is the API level of 18. I personally used the result of `DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat()` as fallback. Alternatively you could just ignore the locale for older devices and use `new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy")` there as fallback or try to backport this one method.

**OP Edit**

I tried on Nexus 5x with Android 6 a following code

```
for (Locale locale : locales) {
   format = android.text.format.DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(locale, "MMMyyyy");
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, locale);
   log.debug("{}: {}", locale.getCountry(), dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
```

And here are some result:

- NA: Jul 2016
- AE: يوليو ٢٠١٦
- BG: 07.2016 г.
- CZ: červenec 2016
- FR: Goue 2016
- DE: Juli 2016
- GB: Jul 2016
- FI: heinä 2016
- IT: Lui 2016
- HR: srp 2016.
- RU: июль 2016

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I have updated your answer with my findings. The results are not good for some countries.